# Array out of bounds. How to stop from going negative

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

So, I am working on a project and I cannot get it to stop going out of bounds. The method getPiece(row, col) returns the value of a custom class from a 2d array. The array is from 0 to 7 in both directions. I have to have it so that row and col is never negative or over 7. Please help. Here is my code:

```
public boolean moveLegal(Move m){

        if (getPiece(m.getRow(), m.getColumn()).getType() != Piece.BLANK)
            return false;
        for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++){
            for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++){
                if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) 
                    continue;
                if (vectorLegal(m, dx, dy)) 
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

That is what the information gets passed into

```
private boolean vectorLegal(Move m, int dx, int dy){
        int x = m.getRow() + dx;
        int y = m.getColumn() + dy;
        if (!getPiece(x,y).equals(m.getPlayer().getPiece().getOpposite())) 
            return false;
        x += dx; y += dy;
        while (onBoard(x,y)){
            Piece here = getPiece(x,y);
            if (here.opposite(m.getPlayer().getPiece())) 
                continue;
            if (here.equals(m.getPlayer().getPiece())) 
                return true;
            x += dx; y += dy;
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks for the help with my issue.

EDIT:
Here is the piece method that is accessing the array

```
public Piece getPiece(int row, int column){  
    return board[row][column];
}
```

Comment: post that code where you are accessing 2D array. The problem lies there.

Comment: Done.Added the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this maybe

```
   public boolean legal(int x,int y){return !(x>7||x<0||y<7||y<0);}
```

and put this everyhere...
 you didn't tell me hat should happen if it is illeagal...
 it must be called first in the if statement or it will crash before the check so

```
   if (legal(x,y)&&!getPiece(x,y).equals(m.getPlayer().getPiece().getOpposite())) 
   if(!legal())//some code to get out of here
    Piece here = getPiece(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that checks if the x,y value is still between [0..7][0..7] before you call getPiece.